# CompareTo method error

Tags: java

This Program gives output as

```
-1
1
-12
```

Why -12?? It should return only 1 , -1 or 0 output as compareTo method is used

```
class psp
{
  public static void main(String gg[])
  {
    String a="AMIT";
    String b="BA";
    String c="AB";
    String d="ANURAG";
    System.out.println(a.compareTo(b));
    System.out.println(b.compareTo(c));
    System.out.println(c.compareTo(d));
  }
}
```

Comment: It's returning `lexicographically lesser` number.

Comment: From the doc.... _"Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object."_ Where did you read it should be -1 or 1 ?

Comment: You will always want to read the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From javadocs:

> returns negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this
>   object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

So it can return any integer, not just `-1,0,1`

Answer (score 0):

If you see the Source code of [`String#compareTo(String)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) it compares the string character by character if charater are not equal it returns the diffrence between the character so checking each case.

> `"AMIT".compareTo("BA")`

1. `A != B` return `A - B`(65 - 66) ie `-1`

> `"BA".compareToAb("AB")`

1. `B != A` return `B - A`(66 - 65) ie `1`

> `"AB".compareToAb("ANURAG")`

1. `A == A` condition true check next character.
2. `B != N` return `B - N`(66-78) return `-12`

Answer (score 0):

It will not give output 1,-1,0 as because compareTo() method compare two strings lexicographically.

```
 s1.compareTo(s2)
```

1. compareTo() returns 0, if two s1 lexicagraphically equal to s2.
2. comapareTo() returns value less than 0, if the s2 string is lexicographically          greater than s1 string.
3 compareTo() returns value greater than 0, if the s2 string lexicographically less than s1 string